# Python async TCP server: cannot get sockets from it

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, tcp

I'm trying to simulate a network using asychronious TCP servers and sockets. I used an [example from documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio-tcp-echo-client-protocol) as a starting point for my task. Here's the code of my server class:

```
import asyncio
import socket
import Node

class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, hostNode):
        self.hostNode = hostNode

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data))
        self.hostNode.processIncomingMessage(data)

class NodeServer:
    def __init__(self, hostNode):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.hostNode = hostNode

    def startListening(self):
        self.coro = self.loop.create_server(ServerProtocol(self.hostNode), '', 0, family=socket.AF_INET)
        server = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.coro)

    def getPortNumber(self):
        print(self.coro.sockets)
        portNumber = self.coro.sockets[0].getpeername()[1]
        print(portNumber)
        return portNumber
```

I call `create_server` function with params `''`, `0` and `family=socket.AF_INET` because I need to establish IPv4 version and the OS must give appropriate random port to listen. In the code below I'm trying to get a number of port.
[Documentation says](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-listening-connections), `create_server` function returns `Server` object, and [sockets can be retrieved](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#server) from `sockets` attribute.
But when I run the code, I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'sockets'
```

It happens when executing `self.coro.sockets`

So, that's the issue.

Could someone help me with this, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `create_server` returns a coroutine. The server instance which has the sockets attribute is returned when you call `run_until_complete`. Change the definition of `startListening` to save the return value of `run_until_complete` as `self.server` and modify your `getPortNumber` definition to use that instead. You also need to change `getpeername` to `getsockname` to get the port allocated.

```
class NodeServer:
    def __init__(self, hostNode):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.hostNode = hostNode

    def startListening(self):
        self.coro = self.loop.create_server(ServerProtocol(self.hostNode), '', 0, family=socket.AF_INET)
        self.server = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.coro)

    def getPortNumber(self):
        print(self.server.sockets)
        portNumber = self.server.sockets[0].getsockname()[1]
        print(portNumber)
        return portNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. It really hepled. Can I ask you another question?